# Best way to develop a schedule android application (w/ database)

Tags: c#, android, linq, entity-framework, datagridview

I am currently developing a schedule application for school. I already built a database, and inserted values to it (I already developed a program to read excel files and insert to the database).

Now i am currently trying to see which is the best way to build the application for android, which objective is to build schedules from the database. In windows I would probably build a c# windows form app with a datagridview (Linq and EntityFramework since i am used to it), and etc...

So I am here to ask ways to develop this for android, which program would be more suitable to develop this sort of application and technologies (like Linq and EntityFramework but for that program). I don't mind on learning stuff, since I like to do research, which I guess it's pretty normal in programming.

Edit. The database provider is SQL server management studio 2014. Is eclipse good for this purpose?

Comment: Android Studio + JDK will help you make your Android app

Comment: I'm not sure what help you're asking here. What is your question exactly? How to read database in android? Btw what is your database provider?

Comment: SQL server management studio 2014

Answer (score 0):

If you already have (or planning to have) your app developed in C#, you should consider migrating it into Xamarin (http://xamarin.com/) cross-platform developing IDE.

> "With Xamarin, you write your apps entirely in C#, sharing the same code on iOS, Android, Windows, Mac and more."

Comment: It is, with some restrictions. Check their pricing here: https://store.xamarin.com/